# REST WebAPI Interface as parameter in API Call

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, interface, dependency-injection

I am building a REST API with ASP.NET WebAPI. Everything worked fine, but then I came up with the great idea to use interfaces in all my method calls. After I have changed all the methods i noticed that after setting the parameter in my Controller methods as interfaces, my API calls does not work. I am using OWIN Self host and Unity dependency injection. Here is my relevant code:

Resolving my Interface:

```
      IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

      container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyInterfaceImpl>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
      HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
      config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

My Controller (the part where i get the error)

```
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSomeData([FromUri]IMyInterface searchObject)
    {
         return this._searchService.SearchForData(searchObject);

    }
```

When calling this method i get the error that an interface cannot be created. I unterstand that, but the problem is fixing it. I looked at [ASP.NET Web API Operation with interfaces instead concrete class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119073/asp-net-web-api-operation-with-interfaces-instead-concrete-class) and also at https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/web-api-and-interface-parameters/ and at [ASP.NET Web API Operation with interfaces instead concrete class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119073/asp-net-web-api-operation-with-interfaces-instead-concrete-class), but none of the suggestions worked in my case (always getting the error that an interface cannot be created).

I was wondering if someone has a working example on something like this(on github or elsewhere)  just to check what I am doing wrong (or even an idea what else I could try would be nice)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Because you are passing data from the querystring a different approach is required here. In my blog post that you referenced I did not include that scenario. Since querystrings are handled via Model Binders you need to create a custom model binder.

In my situation I opted for creating a IoCModelBinder as seen below.

```
public class IocModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var targetObject = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(bindingContext.ModelType);
        var valueProvider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetValueProviderFactories().First(item => item is QueryStringValueProviderFactory).GetValueProvider(actionContext);

        foreach (var property in targetObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var valueAsString = valueProvider.GetValue(property.Name);
            var value = valueAsString == null ? null : valueAsString.ConvertTo(property.PropertyType);

            if (value == null)
                continue;

            property.SetValue(targetObject, value, null);
        }

        bindingContext.Model = targetObject;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in use

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches by the criteria specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchCriteriaDto">The search criteria dto.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search([ModelBinder(typeof(IocModelBinder))]IApplicationSearchCriteriaDto searchCriteriaDto)
    {

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Brette

Comment: Since I am using an Owin for self host I don't have the GlobalConfiguration. All I have is an HttpConfiguration but when using it I get an error that there is no method GetValueProviderFactories in HttpConfiguration which accepts System.Web.Http.Controllers.ServicesContainer as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:
[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)
[How to bind to custom objects in action signatures in MVC/WebAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx)
You can't use an Formatter because you data are coming from the URI. I think you can go with the Modelbinder approch from the links.