# ASP.NET Core Web API - Parameter binding does not work when member of a class is an Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a method in my Web API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Registration registration)
{
    // omitted
}
```

I am able to invoke the method but the parameter is always null. Registration class is defined as:

```
public class Registration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IStudent Student { get; set; }
}

public interface IStudent
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IStudent
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

It seems the Student property of Registration being an interface is what's causing this since when I try to replace it with a concrete type, it binds just fine.

How do I make this bind when using an interface? Also, on my original Web API, I am accepting a parameter of type Registration. Is it possible also to make this as an Interface (IRegistration) and still bind?

Comment: What purpose does an interface have in model binding? .NET can only instantiate classes, so which implementation of the interface should it use?

Comment: @CodeCaster: In the old Web API, there are some workarounds like https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/web-api-and-interface-parameters/. I wanted to know if there is also something I can do in Web API Core.

Comment: You could try to write an own json input formatter... (implement `IInputFormatter` and register it in mvc options: `options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new MyJsonInputFormatter());`

Comment: Even if you find a workaround, this remains a bad practice. I agree with @CodeCaster, you shouldn't use interfaces in models.

Comment: Plus it's not worth the effort. There is not much value in abstracting poco classes

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to do some extra coding. An example is implemeted here:

[ASP.NET Web API Operation with interfaces instead concrete class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119073/asp-net-web-api-operation-with-interfaces-instead-concrete-class)

You probably don't want to do this extra code. It can get buggy. You can create POCOs/DTOs and use Automapper to map your business domain models to your POCOs/DTOs.